# website traffic dropped after using aws cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront

I deployed a website using Beanstalk and enabled log file rotation to S3. EMR job is periodically analyzing the logs on S3 to build a dashboard. Now I use cloudfront to improve website performance. After I started using cloudfront, the usage dashboard shows that the traffic on my website dropped significantly. Any idea why and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

I think you may be misunderstanding how a CDN works. Traffic goes to the CDN, and if it has the data cached, it returns the data without ever sending the traffic to your server. That's sort of the whole point of a CDN. The traffic still exists, but since it is going to the CDN instead of your server, there won't be any log of that traffic on your server.

If you want to perform traffic analysis on your log files, you will need to use logs from the CDN you are using. See the documentation on [CloudFront Logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html).

Also, you might want to look into some sort of client-side analytics such as [Google Analytics](https://www.google.com/analytics/) which would be unaffected by the use of a CDN.